# why Higher-Order Components is components?

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component

I'm new to React, still struggling in understanding HOC.

We know that:

**A HOC is a function that accepts a component and returns a new component that wraps around it
to provide additional features.**

for example:

```
export function ProFeature(FeatureComponent) {
    return function(props) {
       if (props.pro) {
          let { pro, ...childProps} = props;
          return <FeatureComponent {...childProps} />
       } else {
         return (
            <h5 className="bg-warning text-white text-center">
                This is a Pro Feature
           </h5>
         )
      }
    }
}
```

so ProFeature is a HOC.

But to call a thing to be a component, it needs to render content directly. For example, for stateless component called customComponent, we should be able to render its content by:

```
<CustomComponent />
```

but we can't do this on HOC as:

```
<ProFeature />   //invalid
```

instead we need to do :

```
let Abc = ProFeature(CustomComponent);
```

then

```
<Abc/>
```

so HOC is not a component? if it is not a component, why it is called High Order Component? shouldn't it be called sth like High Order Function etc?

Answer (score 0):

*"so HOC is not a component?"* - no, why should it? As React docs states:

> "Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component."

---

*"`let abc = ProFeature(customComponent);`"* - it still won't work, since HOC is a curried function, you have to call it once again to return a component.

*"`<abc />`"* - still won't work since component name has to be capitalized:

```
const Abc = ProFeature(props)(customComponent);
<Abc />
```

Comment: if  HOC is not a component, why it has 'C' in its name? shouldn't it be called HOF- High Order Function?

Comment: you're right. They used "C" within the world to let a developer recognize that component has been "transformed" in some kind of ways. That simply means there might be some changes, addition to the original component. But under the hood this technique utilizes the High-order function of JS.

Comment: @secondimage There is already something like High Order Function :) So to avoid mistakes they made a new name for that - High Order Component :)